# is it possible to nest dynamic node-sets in xslt?

Tags: xslt, dynamic, msxsl, node-set

I'd like to know if it is possible to nest dynamic node sets in XSLT and if so, how to select them using xPath.  This is part of a bigger task.  I'm only showing the part that I'm stuck on.

This is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="Tables">
  <xsl:for-each select="Table">
    <xsl:variable name="TableName" select="Name | @Name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Columns">
      <xsl:for-each select="Column">
        <xsl:variable name="ColumnName" select="Name | @Name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Type" select="Type | @Type"/>
        <Column>
          <Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="$ColumnName"/>
          </Name>
          <Type>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Type"/>
          </Type>
        </Column>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <Table>
      <Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="$TableName"/>
      </Name>
      <Columns>
        <xsl:value-of select="$Columns"/>
      </Columns>
    </Table>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($Tables)/Table">
  Table Name: <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set(Columns)/Column" xml:space="preserve">
    Column Name: <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
    Column Type: <xsl:value-of select="Type"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This is my XML:

```
  <Table Name="Product">
    <Column Name="ProductID" Type="int"/>
    <Column Name="Name" Type="string"/>
    <Column Name="Cost" Type="decimal"/>
    <Column Name="Area" Type="decimal?"/>
  </Table>
  <Table Name="Market">
    <Column Name="MarketID" Type="int"/>
    <Column Name="Name" Type="string"/>
    <Column Name="MinimumASP" Type="double"/>
    <Column Name="MaximumASP" Type="double"/>
  </Table>
```

This is the output I'm currently getting:

```
  Table Name: Product
  Table Name: Market
```

This is what I'd like to get:

```
  Table Name: Product
  Column Name: ProductID
  Column Type: int
  Column Name: Name
  Column Type: string
  Column Name: Cost
  Column Type: decimal
  Column Name: Area
  Column Type: decimal?
  Table Name: Market
  Column Name: MarketID
  Column Type: int
  Column Name: Name
  Column Type: string
  Column Name: MinimumASP
  Column Type: double
  Column Name: MaximumASP
  Column Type: double
```

Comment: @user708613: There are two errors: you should be using `<xsl:copy-of select="$Columns"/>` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="$Columns"/>`; `$Columns` is out of scope for those outer most `xsl:for-each` instructions. You should be using `msxsl:node-set($Table)/Table/Columns/Column`.

Comment: I just needed to change value-of to copy-of and it works!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution that doesn't create any temporary trees and doesn't need the `xxx:node-set()` function at all.

Answer (score 0):

**The wanted result can be produced im a much simpler way and there is no need to create any temporary trees**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat(name(..), ' ', name(), ': ', .)"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (wrapped in a single top element to make it well-formed):

```
<t>
    <Table Name="Product">
        <Column Name="ProductID" Type="int"/>
        <Column Name="Name" Type="string"/>
        <Column Name="Cost" Type="decimal"/>
        <Column Name="Area" Type="decimal?"/>
    </Table>
    <Table Name="Market">
        <Column Name="MarketID" Type="int"/>
        <Column Name="Name" Type="string"/>
        <Column Name="MinimumASP" Type="double"/>
        <Column Name="MaximumASP" Type="double"/>
    </Table>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
Table Name: Product
Column Name: ProductID
Column Type: int
Column Name: Name
Column Type: string
Column Name: Cost
Column Type: decimal
Column Name: Area
Column Type: decimal?
Table Name: Market
Column Name: MarketID
Column Type: int
Column Name: Name
Column Type: string
Column Name: MinimumASP
Column Type: double
Column Name: MaximumASP
Column Type: double
```

Comment: This is part of a bigger task and I need the trees for other things.  But thank you - I learned a bit by looking at your solution.